# Action bar with text in the middle of it that is clickable

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to do in my app that i will have a clickable text in the middle of the actionbar like the whatsapp app have ,
In this picture you will see in the actionbar it got details of the person and its clickable , that is the exactly thing i am looking for

[image]

I saw that i can add subtitles and ofcourse the main title of the actionbar but i didnt seem to find a good result for that exact thing
Thanks heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use this way:

```
ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        action.setTitle("Title");
        action.setSubtitle("Sub title");
        action.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

for < 11 Android API use [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

or you can also use [custom layout for actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16029214/1168654) and [actionbar item click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079425/1168654).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7981633/1168654

Comment: What's the question exactly? I think he/she wants Title/subtitle clickable.

Comment: Setting plain title will not make that region of the `ActionBar` clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `TextView` as `CustomView` that will mimic the plain title and at the same time clickable, instead putting it with `setTitle()`. Add click listener to the `TextView` before you supply it to the `ActionBar`. Don't forget to stretch to the size of the `ActionBar`.

Hope this idea helps.

Edit:

To get the same appearance in terms of size of text of the title and subtitle look at styles.xml

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
       parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
</style>



<style name="TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```