# Unable to get reference of the items in the Custom ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, findviewbyid

I am using a RelativeLayout with some items like EditTexts, Buttons to set a Custom ActionBar view. The problem is that I am unable to get the references of the items which are there in that custom view.

Here is the custom view for ActionBar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/actionbar_background"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ab_home"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@color/left_menu_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ab_action_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/action_search_light"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ab_action_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_customAB_font"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="@string/icon_font"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_customAB_tasks"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_customAB_search"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/icon_search"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        android:background="@color/left_menu_background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_user" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how I inflate and `setCustomView` of the ActionBar.

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

    ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);

inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar,null);
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.ab_home); 

ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Home Clicked");
        }
    });
```

This log statement is never run. I Think I am using the `findViewById()` in a wrong way to reference the Buttons.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: just use ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ab_home);  see this ans---->http://stackoverflow.com/a/16079425/1168654

Comment: OMG, it was just a minor thing and I was stuck on it for like 4 hours. The modification did it, Thank you 
You can add it as an answer I'll accept it

BTW can you tell why referencing it using the CustomActionBar did not do the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Dhawal Sodha. Instead of using

`ImageButtonib=(ImageButton)CustomActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.ab_home);`

Use

`ImageButtonib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ab_home);`