# Custom action bar items listener

Tags: android, android-actionbar, listener, android-custom-view

I create custom view for action bar: **action_bar_bets.xml**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionBarProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_user" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actionBarBets"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_betslip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my menu: **action_bar.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/mybetsCount"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar_bets"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

I create action bar in code:

```java
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar_bets, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(view)
```

I tried set OnClickListener to ImageButtons:

*like this:*

```java
ImageButton profile = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.actionBarProfile);
profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

*and like this:*

```java
actionBar.getCustomView().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.actionBarProfile:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

But nothing happened

Can you help me to fix this problem?

**ADD**
Also in this class i have *ListNavigation*

```java
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String label;
try {
    ActivityInfo activityInfo = pm.getActivityInfo(getComponentName(),
            0);
    label = activityInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    label = null;
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String[] navigations = { label, "Sports", "Profile" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getBaseContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner_title_bar,
        android.R.id.text1, navigations);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_title_bar);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
        @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,
            long itemId) {
        switch (itemPosition) {
        case 1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Activity_profile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you have to supply a bit more here. your code in general seems to be correct. And when you use empty phrases like "nothing happened", your brain should always trigger that you can replace that empty phrase with content like the ..... LOGCAT-stacktrace!!

Comment: never seen that, have to look it up-

Comment: I use this code in OptionMenuWithActivity.class. My other classes extends this class.

I use Log before onTouch method, but it's also clear. It seems, that ID of view is not correct

Comment: check my answer. is that the troublemaker?

Comment: mb it helps, also i have actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

Comment: try `actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionBarProfile).setOnClickListener(...)`

Comment: @vasily-sochinsky it's also didn't help

Comment: well what do you mean by nothing happened then? put some Log print inside your `onClick`

Comment: I put MyLog.d(TAG, "1111111111111111111111111111"); but nothing is displayed in LogCat

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184200/unable-to-get-reference-of-the-items-in-the-custom-actionbar) I have the same trouble, but it didn't help me. It seems, that it's all because of actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where i has error.

```java
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
actionBar.setCustomView(view, lp);
```

and delete this code:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

My navigation list overlaps the buttons

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

im not sure where you initialize your buttons, but when it is in something like onCreate() then replace

```
ImageButton profile = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.actionBarProfile);
```

with

```
ImageButton profile = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actionBarProfile);
```

Comment: Yes, in onCreate() method of OptionMenuWithActivity.class. And my other classes extend OptionMenuWithActivity

Comment: then you don't need the view-reference here

Comment: i try this, but it didn't help

Comment: can you edit your whole question and show all your snippets within the methods the really are. Feels like you are summoning a second View-Object that causes confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is example with a Switch but it's the same way for other component

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.export, menu);
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch);
Switch switchOnActionBar = (Switch)item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
switchOnActionBar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

SwitchForActionBar is in switch_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchForActionBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Manuel"
        android:textOn="Auto"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the menu layout

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/myswitch"
        android:title=""
        android:checkable="true"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
        />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

try ontouchlistener for imagebutton :

Change

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

to :

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
```