# How can I set my actionbar app icon onClickListner in Android?

Tags: android, onclick, android-actionbar

> This my code for set app icon in the Actionbar

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.menuaction);
```

Comment: you can make custom toolbar with app icon on left and add on clickListener on that ImageView

try this link it may help if I am getting what you want to achieve
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838155/set-onclick-listener-on-action-bar-title-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in activity

```
 ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
```

or if using Appcompact do

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

then

```
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and override this method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Do stuff
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```