# How to set an OnClickListener to CollapsingToolbarLayout Title

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have the default AppBar layout inside a coordinator layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="start|bottom"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FAFAFA"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <com.petronas.laniakea.view.FixedRatioImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_blue" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

How do I set an OnClickListener for the title TextView? I was able to get the Toolbar private Title TextView, make it public and set an OnClickListener to that view:

```
   toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Field titleField = null;
        try {
            titleField =Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
            titleField.setAccessible(true);
            TextView barTitleView = (TextView) titleField.get(toolbar);
            barTitleView.setOnClickListener(v -> {});
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The code above works fine but I still don't get a click event when I click the title. Any Ideas?
Here is my view hierarchy as it appears on Stetho:
[View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28GYD.png)

Comment: May be you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24838396/900128

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I tried this already returns null, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to set an OnClickListener on the TextView in any sort of an ActionBar or toolbar. The way you are using uses reflection APIs, which, when packaged in a release app, will promptly crash.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I don't like it either. This is why I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by wrapping the `TextView` by `Toolbar`. So, your layout structure be like:

```
<Toolbar ...>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/toolbarTextId" ..../>
</Toolbar>
```

Now, use `OnClickListener` for tap on text.

```
yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // some action
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it is shown as a fixed TextView on the toolbar (not showing the expanding/collapsing animations with the CollapsingToolbarLayout).